Problems updating /etc/hosts file via command bash -c
Trying to update host configuration file via command :
$ sudo bash -c 'echo $(minikube ip) blue.io green.io >> /etc/hosts'

Command was passed, but host configuration file /etc/hosts was not updated.
If after command above, I pass the following command:
$ sudo bash -c 'echo $(minikube ip) blue.io green.io | cat'

The following message is returned:
"Profile "minikube" not found. Run "minikube profile list" to view all profiles.  To start a cluster, run: "minikube start" blue.io green.io. 

If I run command below:
$ sudo nano /etc/hots

I can see two times the following message at the bottom of the script:
"Profile "minikube" not found. Run "minikube profile list" to view all profiles.  To start a cluster, run: "minikube start" blue.io green.io. 

I resorted to updating file manually using nano command, by deleting message from above, and entering a line manually:
xxx.xxx.99.100   blue.io green.io
$ nano /etc/hosts

I wonder why code sudo bash -c.... did not update configuration file as expected.
Further information:

code is run on a ubuntu Linux VM with enabled nested virtualisation, - running a minikube cluster(kubernetes)
2 configuration maps are setup to customise each of the webservers from a yaml file

I read posts like Webserver /etc/hosts file questions but I could not find the answer to my question.

Try sudo bash -xc 'echo $(minikube ip) blue.io green.io >> /etc/hosts' where the -x tells bash to show what it does.

You appear to have configuration, such as environment variables, present in your user account but that is not globally accessible to accounts such as root.
As a workaround you can modify your statement to generate the IP address as your own account and then use root just to modify the /etc/hosts file:
echo "$(minikube ip) blue.io green.io" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts

As a useful side-effect you will see the line that has been added to /etc/hosts (append > /dev/null to the command if this is not required).
